# Android response from script problem

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am using HttpClient using POST method to send a string to a script. The script works fine, it just checks to see whether the table exists in a db. If the table exists "1" is echo'd back.

In the following code everything works fine

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("//remote//script.php");

                    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tblname", concatenated));
                    try 
                    {
                        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                    } 
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try 
                    {
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                        entity = response.getEntity();
                        res = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //this is now the echo back from the script, "1" means tbl already exists exists 

                    } 
                    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    Toast msg1 = Toast.makeText(main.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg1.getXOffset() / 2, msg1.getYOffset() / 2);
                    msg1.show();
                    SavePreferences("prefs", concatenated);
                    //fire the authed intent
                    startauthedactivity();
                    }
```

If the table supplied to the script exists 1 is displayed in the toast at the end, if it doesnt exists then the toast is empty, this is correct behavior.

When I apply an -if- to the response it always calls the true condition , even if the table exists. In the following code if the table exists then res should = 1 and the condition is not true so the else block should fire but it never does. However, weirdly, if i pass a table which exists to the script then the toast does actually display a 1...

```
if(res != "1")
                {

                Toast msg1 = Toast.makeText(main.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg1.getXOffset() / 2, msg1.getYOffset() / 2);
                msg1.show();
                SavePreferences("prefs", concatenated);
                //fire the authed intent
                startauthedactivity();
                }
                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you have to use equals() to compare strings

```
if("1".equals(res)) {...
```

Note that you should use `"1".equals(res)` instead of `res.equals("1")`.

If res is `null`, the first one will work, since `equals` handles null arguments.
The second will get a `NullPointerException` because res is null :)

Comment: 2 of the fastest answers ever.just checking :D

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if(res != "1")
```

to

```
if(res.equals("1"))
```

Why?

`==` compares the reference of the object (it's position in the memory). `equals` compares the contents of the string.

Comment: 2 of the fastest answers ever.just checking :D